# Having a issue with the "Share" feature Facebook Fan page

Tags: facebook, social-networking

My friend has created about 20 Facebook fan page for the website. www.AvailDiscounts.com

Now the issue is, when we click on the wall post to "share" with other friends, its taking to another page where it displays the meta tags and the title of the login page instead of displaying the exact post.

Please find the fan page of the website:

> http://www.facebook.com/pages/Avail-Discounts-Chicago/195486540483072

How to over come this issue.

The Query can be found in the following link with images:

> http://getsatisfaction.com/rssgraffiti/topics/issue_with_share_button_when_using_rss_graffiti

Please help

As far as i have checked this seems to be an issue with the RSS Graffiti application in Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, and the passing of the auth information is kind of scary, but anyway, I'd make the href of the post something along the lines of this:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response

More information is available here: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

1) Are you posting the correct link in RSS Graffiti?

It seems all of your fan page links redirect me to the **Avail-Discounts-Chicago** home page. It's either it is non-existent, deal closed or bad URL supplied.

2) RSS Graffiti posts differently than Share button

RSS Graffiti prepares your data, image link title and description before posting to the page stream. The default Facebook Share button does not. What it does is get the URL, scrape that URL with information, which can be defined through [opengraph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). Make sure your links / deals have their **meta:og**'s.

Comment: Hi Dragonjet, 

Regarding your first point, let me first fix the RSS updating issue in Facebook :). and i will try the second one. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Dear DragonJet,

My doubt is, will the correct deal values will appear if i have implemented "Open Graph" when "Share button" is clicked.

Open Graph seems to be dealing with LIKE button in FB.

Thanks a Lot

Comment: Yes, Open graph is not only for the like button, but also for the share. They both scrape the URLs for open graph tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I have one more query... Is it possible to implement the Open Graph when updating the Facebook Fan page using the RSS feeds. I tried to search on the internet... I could not find any details regarding how the open graph can be implemented in RSS feeds. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: RSS feeds of our website can be found in 

http://availdiscounts.com/daily-deals/xmlfeed/chicago.html

Comment: if RSS graffiti automatically posts in your behalf using links from the RSS, then there is nothing we can do. You cannot use Open Graph Tags in RSS. Open graph tags are used if you only provide links. RSS Graffiti not only provides links but all other info like title and description. For them open graph is useless.